# Force TableView Cells Onto One Page

Tags: swift, uitableview

Is it possible to force a table view to autosize however many cells it has, to fit one page and disable scrolling? Ex: 1 cell, height = 100%, 2 cells, height = 50% each. I'd like to do something similar to a Stacked View, except the amount of items I will be stacking will vary every time. Thanks!

Comment: you can always return height for tableview cell and manually calculate screen height divided by number of entries

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my project and it worked for me.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView.rowHeight = view.frame.height / CGFloat(data.count)
}
```